# Content of the input is "visually" unchanged

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

EDIT UPDATED CODE WITH CORRECTION AND FURTHER EXPLAINATION, THANKS TO ALL

I have a problem with some inputs.

My code dynamically produces some `<a>` elements, and some `<inputs>` as well.

Let's say these `<a>` have `class="aclass" data-input="pid"`, the inputs have `id="pid"`

My code:

```
 $("#prod_category").on("change", (function(evt) { //this appens when this select change
    evt.preventDefault();
    $("#div1").remove();                      
    $("#div2").remove();

    var valu = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

    //I build some divs

    var left = "<div id="div1">";
    var right = "<div id="div2">";

    //we fill further these divs, then close

    left  += "</div>";
    right += "</div>";

    $("#static_existing_div").append(left);
    $("#static_existing_div2").prepend(right);

    $("#div1").accordion({     //I use accordion (jQuery ui) on this div
                          collapsible: true
                        });
}));

//FOMM
//the links <a> with class="aclass" are located inside div1
//I have to use $(static parent element).on(evt, ".aclass", ...) I choose document
$(document).on("click", ".aclass" ,function(evt) {  
    evt.preventDefault();
    var ele = $(this);
    var datain = ele.data("input");

    if($("#" + datain).length) {
       var elein = $("#" + datain);
       elein.attr("value", "TT");
       alert(elein.val());
    }
});
```

This alerts me "TT", and the value of the input is TT indeed but the content of the input is "visually" unchanged. I tried with val() too.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please explain in detail, what do you mean by  `"visually" unchanged` here?

Comment: sorry for the confusion in variable names, I changed them to be simple for the sake of simplicity, also the code is simplified. But assume dataf = datain. and length() yes of course is a property not a function.     By "visually" I mean the image of text in the browser, the DOM.

Comment: Ok, just like I was fearing, I am able to change value of an existing input. But not a dinamically created one, even if it's already present in the dom when the click event fires. I don't know maybe because the selector is the document? Further considerations after.

Comment: Put up your code for dynamic input

Comment: done, code updated

Comment: `"<div id="div2">"; ` should be `"<div id='div2'>"; `

Comment: yes, ok a part from correctly escaping ahah, still didn't find a solution. When I'll  find I'll post here

Comment: Check my answer. I added hyperlink and textbox through js. It works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me for dynamically added hyperlink and textboxes also. Below snippet works fine for me on a html page and visual representation is ok.

```js
$("#prod_category").on("change", (function(evt) { //this appens when this select change
    //evt.preventDefault();
    $("#div1").remove();                      
    $("#div2").remove();

    var valu = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

    //I build some divs

    var left = "<div id='div1'><a class='aclass' data-input='p1'>One</a><input id='p1' type='text'/>";
    var right = "<div id='div2'><a class='aclass' data-input='p2'>Two</a><input id='p2' type='text'/>";

    //we fill further these divs, then close

    left  += "</div>";
    right += "</div>";

    $("#static_existing_div").append(left);
    $("#static_existing_div2").prepend(right);

    $("#div1").accordion({     //I use accordion (jQuery ui) on this div
                          collapsible: false
                        });
}));

//FOMM
//the links <a> with class="aclass" are located inside div1
//I have to use $(static parent element).on(evt, ".aclass", ...) I choose document
$(document).on("click", ".aclass" ,function(evt) {  
    evt.preventDefault();
    var ele = $(this);
    var datain = ele.data("input");

    if($("#" + datain).length) {
       var elein = $("#" + datain);
       elein.attr("value", "TT");
       alert(elein.val());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<select id="prod_category">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
  <option value="1">3</option>
  <option value="1">4</option>
  <option value="1">5</option>
  </select>

   <div id="static_existing_div"></div>
   <div id="static_existing_div2"></div>
```

Comment: It works for me too, probably some other js library messes things up :(   https://jsfiddle.net/7Lthnr9n/3/

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you are getting the id of the input elements from the data-input field of the `<a>` tag and trying to change that element. However after you check if that element exists or not in:

```
if($("#" . datain).length())
```

you try to change another element but not the found one?

```
var elein = $("#" + dataf);
```

What is `dataf` here? If you want to change the element you have just found, it should be

```
var elein = $("#" + datain);
```

More elaboration is needed if your goal is different. Couldn't comment because of my reputation, would ask for more clarity otherwise.

Comment: sorry for the confusion in variable names, I changed them to be simple for the sake of simplicity, also the code is simplified.  assume dataf = datain

Comment: yes sorry, quick edits to render the code simpler for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your code giving lot of confusion. My assumption is on `data-input` you will get some value, an `input` filed should have `id` with the same value. Based on that `id`, you want to assign the value.

You have the confusion on how to combine the value with `#` and how to assign the value to the new field. Look at the code below, you will get some clear idea.

```
 $(document).on("click", ".aclass" ,function(evt) {  
  evt.preventDefault();
  var ele = $(this);                 
  var datain = ele.data("input");
  if(datain) {   
    var elein = $("#"+datain);     
    elein.attr("value", "TT");      
    alert(elein.val());             
  }
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/jfwsx9h6/)

Comment: yes, ok it makes sense, my code is the same as yours, but it does not seems to work. I don't know, is it possible that the faulty component is the input, since the input is also created dinamically?

Answer (score 0):

There are certain obvious syntax errors in your code such as

```
$("#" . datain).length()
```

is invalid, you it must be length

```
$("#" + datain).length
```